# Xcode 7.0 (iOS9 SDK) layout shifted on iPhone 6-6plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

I have a problem with the new iOS9 SDK. Now when I compile with this  SDK my view is crop like an iPhone 5 (see the image below) Even on a collectionviewController... I didn't have the problem before.
[image: Iphone 6 version]

Comment: Use AutoLayout to manage your views